# Get gmail authorize token and refresh token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using Ruby on Rails to access my Gmail account and read emails. I recently changed the password of my account. Since then, I am unable to access the emails using the credentials I was using previously. That is, after changing the password, the client id, client secret and refresh token are invalid.

Tried creating new client id and client secret. But in order to generate the refresh token, I need the authorization code. For this I am performing the following steps:

1. Run command: gmail_cli authorize
2. Insert newly created client id and client secret
3. Access the url returned in the terminal.

On accessing the URL, it throws an error:

> Authorization Error
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

I understand that the issue is with the redirect URI. But where should I add it? And what should the URI be?

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the passwords of your account, all refresh tokens will be revoked for that user when one of the gmail scopes was used to create it.

You should simply need to authorize your application again.   Remember though with the remove of OOB that you can no longer use the redirect uri of `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`  you should instead use localhost.

```
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:port or http://[::1]:port">http://[::1]:port or
```

- [Making Google OAuth interactions safer by using more secure OAuth flows](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html)
- [Out-Of-Band (OOB) flow Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Does the client id and client secret change on changing the password?

Comment: No the client id and client secret define your project in google cloud console. They should not change.   I think your just having a problem because you haven't authorized it since they removed oob.    If you have a credetinals.json file downloaded open it in a text editor and remove the oob redirect uri there should be one there already with localhost

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue. Hence sharing the details for anyone who stumbles on a similar issue.
As mentioned by @DalmTo, the client id and secret do not change. I had created new credentials and was trying to get the authorization key for it which was leading to an error.

So the solution is that using the same credentials we just need to create new access key and refresh token.

Comment: Since the answer was the same as DaImTo, you could have added the comment under her answer since there was no major difference from the one provided by her.